# Compiling issues with mono and multi-threaded application

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, mono, gmcs

I am trying to compile a C# app that uses the TPL for linux, using mono.  The app was built on windows using VS. i am trying to compile the cs classes via gmcs.  However i am getting this error:

```
gmcs Main.cs FileUtil.cs BH.cs 

BH.cs(6,24): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Tasks' does not exist in the
namespace `System.Threading'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Main.cs(17,24): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Tasks' does not exist in the
namespace `System.Threading'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
BH.cs(6,24): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Tasks' does not exist in the
namespace `System.Threading'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Compilation failed: 3 error(s), 0 warnings
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

`gmcs` targets 2.0 corlib. Try to use `mcs` instead.