# compiling F# on linux with TPL

Tags: f#, compiler-errors, mono, task-parallel-library

I am pretty feeling pretty stumped with this issue... i am trying to compiling an F# prog that uses the TPL.  I am using an up to data verson of mono which compiles C# and TPL.

The F# project is for a uni, which need to be run on there machines, so i have limited access i.e. no sudo rights. it is also commandline driven

These are errors generated:

Microsoft (R) F# 2.0 Compiler build 2.0.0.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

/home/msc/sg315/fs/MapSkel.fs(12,23): error FS0039: The namespace 'Tasks' is not defined

/home/msc/sg315/fs/MapSkel.fs(23,5): error FS0039: The namespace or module 'Parallel' is not defined

/home/msc/sg315/fs/MapSkel.fs(31,3): error FS0039: The namespace or module 'Parallel' is not defined

/home/msc/sg315/fs/MapSkel.fs(44,5): error FS0039: The namespace or module 'Parallel' is not defined

/home/msc/sg315/fs/MapSkel.fs(52,12): error FS0039: The namespace or module 'Parallel' is not defined

/home/msc/sg315/fs/MapSkel.fs(55,12): error FS0039: The namespace or module 'Parallel' is not defined

/home/msc/sg315/fs/MapSkel.fs(61,12): error FS0039: The namespace or module 'Parallel' is not defined

/home/msc/sg315/fs/MapSkel.fs(68,12): error FS0039: The namespace or module 'Parallel' is not defined

/home/msc/sg315/fs/MapSkel.fs(77,13): error FS0039: The namespace or module 'Parallel' is not defined

/home/msc/sg315/fs/BHList.fs(60,14): error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'ReadLines' is not defined
-bash-4.1$

It obviously needs library references but have no idea which ones... 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As in your previous question [Compiling issues with mono and multi-threaded application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287254/compiling-issues-with-mono-and-multi-threaded-application), the problem is that you are targeting a version of .NET which is too old.

You can download the new compiler source here http://github.com/fsharp/fsharp.  Newer versions of the compiler automatically target a more moder .NET.  This can be compiled and installed into a home directory (no root required).